# Prove by induction $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+...+\sqrt{n}\ge\frac{2}{3}n\sqrt{n}$ for all positive integers

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, radicals

Assumption: $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+...+\sqrt{k}\ge\frac{2}{3}k\sqrt{k}$

Prove true for $n=k+1$ $$\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+...+\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}\ge\frac{2}{3}(k+1)\sqrt{k+1}$$

I'm upto :$$\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+...+\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}\ge\frac{2}{3}k\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}$$after which I'm stuck.

Comment: This looks like a proof that would be easily done by comparing a Riemann sum to an integral of the square root function from 0 to k.

Comment: A recent question about the same problem: [Prove by induction that $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+...+\sqrt{n} \geq \frac{2}{3}n\sqrt{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2926270).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the induction step, you want to show that:
$$
\frac{2k\sqrt{k} + 3\sqrt{k+1}}{3} \geq \frac{2(k+1)\sqrt{k+1}}{3} \\
2k\sqrt{k} + 3\sqrt{k+1} \geq 2k\sqrt{k+1} + 2\sqrt{k+1}\\
$$
Working backwards:
$$
2k\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1} \geq 2k\sqrt{k+1} \\
2k\sqrt{k} \geq (2k-1)\sqrt{k+1} \\
4k^2 \times k \geq (4k^2 - 4k+1)(k+1) = 4k^3 - 4k^2 + k + 4k^2 - 4k+ 1 = 4k^3 - 3k + 1
$$
The rest should follow since $k \geq \frac1{3}$, since the induction is over the positive integers.

Comment: I don't quite get how you got your second line

Comment: I expanded the right-hand side and then subtracted $2\sqrt{k+1}$ on both sides. An edit has been made showing this.